# Changing Referenced Cell when Cell with Reference is changed

Tags: excel

I honestly didn't know how else to word that title, but what I'm wanting to know if it's possible is to be able to have many sheets that represent data, and have a front page that looks up the needed values, but allows you to change the referenced values by changing the cell that is displaying, basically like you would be able to do with an object reference in Java, where you could create a new variable with the original object, but changes to the new variable would change the original object.

If it requires VBA, I'll likely just make a quick mobile or web-mobile app to do the same thing.  I just wanted to know if it was possible, since the entire thing is already in Excel, and I didn't even know what terminology to search for to find it on my own.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Feel like elaborating?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what cell you would change (from what value to which other value) and what effect that should have? Which cells should then change from what to what?

Comment: Example...  Well, say I have sheet 'Overview', which has fields 'Week', 'Weight' and 'Waist (inches)', and cells next to each, with the last two referring to a sheet based on what is in the cell next to Week.  If Week is 1, then sheet Week 1 is referenced, and the values available for Weight and Waist are shown next to their labels on Overview.  The thing I want is, when I change the cells on Overview, I don't want their references removed, but to have those changes made be applied to Week 1's cells instead.